# Cobol - is it possible to delete records in Sequential file?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I need to delete first x rows and I need to do it via Cobol.
Is it possible? It seems the DELETE statement is for VSAM files only?

Answer (score 7):

You say you must do this via COBOL but do not provide a reason.  Typically this type of operation is done via your shop's SORT utility.  Mainframe SORT utilities normally include sophisticated record selection criteria.

Yes it is possible to do this with COBOL.  You are correct in your implied statement that DELETE is for VSAM only.  For a sequential file, you must read the entire file, ignoring the first x records, and write the rest to a new output file.  I would suggest writing your COBOL code such that it accepts a parameter indicating how many records (x in your example) to ignore, exiting with a specific return code if there are less than x records in the file.

If you desire, you can use the C runtime routines (`fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose`) for file I/O to make your program generic and not specific to one particular file.  COBOL requires the LRECL to be known at compile time, the C runtime routines, directly callable from COBOL via the grace of Language Environment (LE), remove this requirement.

To reiterate: this is typically done with your shop's SORT utility.

Comment: Too bad I can only upvote once. Please use SORT, not only is it the better way to do it, its also faster and more efficient than pretty much anything you will write. So if you are processing a lot of data in the file, the I/O and CPU usage will be much less on a sort than a COBOL program

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the best answer to dropping a few records at the front of a file is to use the installation sort utility.

However, in the generic pattern sense, where you want to delete some records from a file based on business logic implemented in COBOL, the best approach is to read the original input file, filter it through your logic, and write a new output file.

Once that job step completes, immediately use the system utilities to either REPRO the new file into the old file, or, if online availability is a thing, delete the old file and RENAME the new file to the old file name.

Answer (score 2):

Using COBOL, you may restrain from writing the first x rows into the sequential file based on conditional expressions. 
In one of my recent assignment, we had to update a Master file based on the **Type**  field in the Transaction file. The type would have one byte value and the possible values are 'A' (means ADD the record to the Master file), 'M' (means MODIFY the record in the Master file) and 'D' (means DELETE the record from the Master file). For the type 'D' transaction, we just skipped the record without writing it to the new master file.